# why is sportspress asking for FTP credentials on a local installation?

Tags: plugins, ftp

I am new to WordPress and am trying to build a league site. 
I found this plugin called sportspress and managed to correct the permissions on my local WordPress server to, after downloading the plugin, installing to the server.

It seems like it installed OK and then it asked for FTP credentials. Why would this be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Third-party plugin support is off topic on [wordpress.se]. All the guidelines of this site can be found in the [help]. You should ask the plugin maintainer for support. Should this still be an issue with WordPress itself, then it most likely means, you didn't manage to set the permissions correctly. In that case you need to provide detailed information, otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: Ok, thanks, apologies for not observing the guidelines.

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to inform you, otherwise the rejection of a question often can be perceived as unwelcoming. Just as a hint, if you give detailed information, that can be somewhat tied back to WordPress core functionality, then it is much more likely to get an answer anyway.

Comment: I used to work with the people who make SportsPress and I have never encountered this problem. I would also recommend you get in touch with them. They will be more than happy to help you out.

Comment: In the end, it had nothing to do with either WordPress or the third-party plugin. It was entirely my bad! I solved it with `chown -Rf www-data.www-data /var/www/html/wordpress`.